# Is it normal for ns.sipgeo.t-mobile.com to bypass DNS and VPN settings on iOS, iPadOS, and macOS?

Tags: vpn, mobile

I’ve been using NextDNS to monitor DNS lookups on my devices in an effort to figure out how they’re being remotely controlled and I notice that ns.sipgeo.t-mobile.com is simply able to bypass both DNS and VPN settings on my iOS, iPadOS, and macOS devices.

Instead of using the DNS resolver app (i.e., the NextDNS app), (NextDNS) configuration profile, or DNS resolution information provided by the active VPN (e.g., in the hide.me VPN app) lookups for this URL simply bypasses all of them together and uses the DNS information for the connection.

That information can be controlled on a wi-fi network connection, but on a connection emanating from an eSIM/SIM card where the DNS information is always provided by the telecom provider, that means connections to ns.sipgeo.t-mobile.com are essentially invisible and therefore unblockable when a SIM card is in a device.

**Is this insecure bypass behavior normal and, if it is, why?**

On macOS, connections to this URL appear to emanate from the /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/Support/CommCenter app and inexplicably continue trying to establish an ISAKMP connection on UDP port 500 even after I’ve signed out of iMessage and rebooted the machine. The same process makes TCP port 443 connections to eas3.msg.t-mobile.com.

I’ve noticed a similar phenomenon on Android with Google Fi where connections are instead made to nwp.t-mobile.com and vaspbon-int.msg.t-mobile.com in a way that doesn’t appear in my Android firewall logs.

**Why do I suspect that this is related to malware?**

Signing out of my Apple ID account seems to affect the ability of my devices to be controlled, except my iPhone 14 Pro, which has an eSIM that I can’t easily remove and re-add. Removing the SIM cards from my iPhone 13 and iPad Pro seemed/seems to prevent them from controlling the devices. My iMac has no SIM capability, but can nonetheless be controlled when signed into my Apple ID account. Blocking Apple domains seems to sometimes work and not work in blocking the malware, which would make sense if the problem is not the Apple domains themselves, but that they’re propagating the T-Mobile information from my phone to my other Apple devices which is then retained after the domains have been unblocked and reblocked, making the blocking ineffective.

Google Fi likewise uses the T-Mobile network.

I also ran into a case where a previous Android phone could seemingly be controlled with an inactive Tello SIM card. Tello utilizes the T-Mobile network. (On Android, they’ve done things like make the wi-fi indicator invisible even when connected to wi-fi, so it’s possible there was other means.)

They can also control my Apple Watch when the eSIM card is enabled, but I haven’t spent much time testing the security of that device.

Comment: *"lookups for this URL simply bypasses all of them together and uses the DNS information for the connection."* - I don't understand what you mean by "and uses the DNS information for the connection.". But in general DNS is just one mechanism of name resolution and other mechanism are a local host file or things like mDNS. Application might also use their own DNS settings, i.e. not use the system name lookup mechanism (which includes local host file, mDNS and DNS server)

Comment: DNS information for the connection is the DNS information automatically derived from the router or mobile network or manually specified for a wi-fi or Ethernet connection. Apple devices allow a DNS provider to be explicitly provided (via DNS on iOS and iPadOS or DNS Settings configuration profiles or VPNs on macOS), but these security restrictions are ignored for certain T-Mobile domains without any obvious explanation.

Comment: In general the configured remote DNS server is only used for domains which cannot be resolved by other means, like static entries in host file or mDNS. Apart from that connections can also be established without even doing a DNS lookup first, just by knowing the relevant IP address up-front. So DNS based filtering does not have the full visibility of what is going on.

Comment: Yet the domains are obviously being resolved if they appear in DNS resolution logs without a SIM card inserted and disappear otherwise. If I specify the resolver as an IP address, there’s no explicable reason to bypass the system DNS and VPN settings.

Comment: I understand that you don't like it the way it works, i.e. that there are some predefined mappings between domain name and IP pushed to the system and thus you don't have the control by NextDNS you would like to have. But, I don't see this necessary as malware activity as you claim.

Comment: I think you need to be more explicit about your wording: "ns.sipgeo.t-mobile.com is simply able to bypass both DNS and VPN settings" -- that makes no sense. What does this mean? "lookups for this URL" -- do you mean lookups for the *domain name servers*? "prevent them from controlling the devices" -- them who? What's being controlled? "blocking the malware" -- wait, you said you *suspected* malware, now you state that you are infected? Which is it? This whole post repeated "controlling my device" but you never explain what's being controlled.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you are jumping to wild conclusions and using circular logic to "prove" that what you suspect is happening because you can fit some facts to a narrative. What I see from your details is "my device is connecting to pre-defined domain name servers from my ISP and I can't prevent it". Nothing here suggests malware.

Comment: I just did a google search for "sipgeo" and the top hit was from the NextDNS forums: https://help.nextdns.io/t/y4hzff7/nextdns-blocking-all-textmedia-messages#h7hlq5k suggesting that that DNS server be white listed. Have you done any looking up of this problem? And have you looked to see if your NextDNS has a whitelist entry for this domain?